Sessions Conflict on Magento 2 StoreFront
I am using ScandiPwa as storefront and Third party Marketplace Module with Vendor Dashboard
Scandipwa is using JWT token based login while Marketplace module is using Magento Customer Session to login User to Dashboard
Issue:
When Vendor gets Logged In to Dashboard and for some reason he refresh the storefront he gets Logged Out from vendor dashboard
Can anyone help with for finding a solution of this issue
